# scroll pane graphic bug

Tags: java, jscrollpane, paint, graphic

I got an unexpected behavior on my JScrollPane:
 My ScrollPanel is filled with different panels
(Transparency is needed because in the end I will have images in background instead of just colors)

I made a quick example of my problem:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.Border;


 public class ScrollPaneTest extends JPanel{

  ScrollPaneTest(){

    JPanel Content = new JPanel();
    BoxLayout ColumnLayout = new BoxLayout(Content,BoxLayout.Y_AXIS);
    Content.setLayout(ColumnLayout);
    for(int i = 0 ; i < 10 ; i++){
        JPanel pane = new JPanel();
        JLabel elem = new JLabel("element "+i);
        pane.setBackground(new Color(0,0,0,125));
        pane.add(elem);
        Content.add(pane);

    }



    Content.setBackground(Color.ORANGE);

    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(Content);
    scrollPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100,100));
    scrollPane.setBackground(new Color(0,0,0,250));
    add(scrollPane);
 }

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    JFrame f =  new JFrame();
    JPanel bck = new JPanel();
    bck.setBackground(Color.RED);
    bck.add(new ScrollPaneTest());
    f.add(bck);

    f.setSize(200, 200);
    f.setVisible(true);
  }

}
```

With this you can see that when I scroll, the graphics are all messed up :/
Thanks for Helping :p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**I have the Following Solution for your Problem**

When you scroll through the elements the elements are not repainted so you need to repaint them when you scroll the scroll bar. Add the following code after this line `JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(Content);` it will work!

```
    scrollPane.getVerticalScrollBar().addAdjustmentListener(new AdjustmentListener(){
        @Override
        public void adjustmentValueChanged(AdjustmentEvent e) {
            repaint();
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks man \o/

I did think I may have to implement such an event on the scrollpane .
Your method is very simple and convenient :)